# Should MVVM be used on iOS?

Tags: ios, mvvm

I decided to test out the MVVM structure in a MapKit/CoreLocation project of mine with Swift.

Even though I was really hopeful at the beginning about the improved structure, it ended up being more problematic than providing help. Since iOS doesn't have UIBinding, I found myself writing more code and hence the code was becoming harder to track.

Did you tried MVVM on iOS? Did it help? What's your experience like?

Comment: Hi, this may help you http://www.raywenderlich.com/74106/mvvm-tutorial-with-reactivecocoa-part-1

Comment: @GovindaraoKondala Yeah, I saw that but in general I'm curious about other people's experiences using MVVM on iOS. Thanks.

Comment: MVVM is always worth doing it, when the project exceeds a size and you want to decouple your code from your view/application, but MVVM also has a steep learning curve. You shouldn't expect to understand MVVM in 1 or 2 weeks. Initially it is more effort (=more code) to get started, even if you're familiar with it. It pays of afterwards, as the code stays easier to maintain and extend and especially to unit-test

Comment: @Can Sürmeli are you working on swift and Objective C ?

Comment: @GovindaraoKondala only Swift